# discord.py: problem when help command not have cog mentioned in the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, python-3.8

my code:

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import re
import os

class Help2(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    

    @commands.command()
    async def help2(self, ctx, * cog=None):
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Command of {self.bot.user.name}", description=f"Prefix = {self.bot.command_prefix}\n*Per avere maggiori informazioni su ogni comando digita `{self.bot.command_prefix}help <nome comando>`.*")
        
        for command in self.bot.get_cog("Ban").get_commands():
            embed.add_field(name=f"{command.name} - {command.description}.", value=f"↳ **Syntax:** `{command.usage}`")

        for command in self.bot.get_cog("Kick").get_commands():
            embed.add_field(name=f"{command.name} - {command.description}.", value=f"↳ **Syntax:** `{command.usage}`")

        for command in self.bot.get_cog("Unban").get_commands():
            embed.add_field(name=f"{command.name} - {command.description}.", value=f"↳ **Syntax:** `{command.usage}`")
        
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)



    @help2.error
    async def help2_error(self, ctx, error):
        await ctx.send(f"```{error}```")


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Help2(bot))
````

when I run this code, the bot have must send cogs mentioned
but if one cog of the others cogs mentioned in code was "offline" or file for cog doesn't
exist all the code doesn't work.

the error:

```
Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_commands'
```

I want the code to run even if one or more gears were "offline" or only mention online cogs

how I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument `*cog` is being passed as a tuple of words that follow your command, and throws an error if you try `*cog=None`.

What we can do instead is add a check for it and if user does not specify a cog, it takes all. If the cog is unloaded, it will throw an error since `self.bot.get_cog(cog)=NoneType object` We can instead use `try` and `except`

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def help2(self, ctx, *cog):
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Command of {self.bot.user.name}", description=f"Prefix = {self.bot.command_prefix}\n*Per avere maggiori informazioni su ogni comando digita `{self.bot.command_prefix}help <nome comando>`.*")

        if len(cog)==0:
            cog = ("Ban", "Kick", "Unban")
        
        for i in cog:
            try:
                for command in self.bot.get_cog(i).get_commands():
                    embed.add_field(name=f"{command.name} - {command.description}.", value=f"↳ **Syntax:** `{command.usage}`")
            except:
                pass # What will happen if cog is unloaded, or nothing with pass
        
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: thanks for explanation
I had in mind to do something similar, but I didn't know where to start and in fact when I tried to do `cog = None` it gave an error.
so thanks very much